# Magento / Paypal reserve funds to charge months later

Tags: magento, paypal

I am looking to see if there is a way to use Paypal within Magento to have a authorize a charge to an account, and only do the capture several months later. We are designing a site where the lead time on orders could be months as the products need to be created once ordered.

Based on what I have seen in Paypals documentation (links below), I believe there is a time limit of about a month, however I thought it prudent to confirm this.

Thank you,

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/authcapture/
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/admin/auth-capture/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Authorizations normally only allow up to 30 days from the original transaction date. There isn't a way to guarantee those funds for an extended period of time, though you can reauthorize for a short time, you would not be able to extend it for months at a time.

The best way to go about this would be to utilize Reference Transaction which allows you to run a new transaction off an existing transaction.

Documentation: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/DoReferenceTransaction_API_Operation_NVP/

How this would work is you would run an intial charge usually a smaller amount then your system would store the transaction ID from the original payment and then you would use the reference transaction API to run a new transaction for the remaining amount at the time you are requesting.

Note, Reference Transaction is not enabled by default so you would need to contact PayPal Business Support to get a request submitting to activate this service.

Comment: Thank  you very much for this information. This gives me a possible solution to present. We will contact PP and see what can be done!

Comment: For future googlers, this seems to work well, PayPal MTS was quick to enable for Sandbox. Off the shelf plugin for Magento for integration. Need to work out the flow, we think we will charge people a small deposit to do the initial billing agreement, and then the full amount when product is ready.